# Is there a character limit for win32print.TextOut() in python

Tags: python

I have been referring to Tim Golden python docs and I used the code under "Single image: use PIL and win32ui" on [TimGoldenPrintGuide](http://timgolden.me.uk/python/win32_how_do_i/print.html).

I'm trying to print a long bill with an image on the top. For printing the image I have used the same code as in the guide. I have used the code below instead of `hDC.DrawText` to add the text. If I have a very long text its not getting printed till the end. I used the `win32print.WritePrinter` to print the same text file and I got it completely. But now as I need to print an image on top I have to use this method with a device context.

In there I pass my string to this TextOut command. So is there is a character length how can I bypass it? Or what is the best way of doing this?

```
printer_name = sys.argv[1]
filename = sys.argv[2]
image_path = sys.argv[3]
pointSize = int(sys.argv[4])
bill_format = ""

with open(filename) as f:
    for line in f:
        bill_format += line
for line in (bill_format).split("\n"):
    hDC.TextOut((printer_margins[0] + line_space),Y,line)
    Y += int (line_space * 1.25)
```

Comment: hello, buddy
I'm facing the exact same thing have u solved this?
thank u.